# bitbucket-push-and-pull-request not working with bitbucket push

Tags: jenkins, triggers, bitbucket

I have this configuration...  I'm unsing the kenkins plugin : bitbucket-push-and-pull-request

I can trigger the job when doing a PR merge...  However it doesn't work when doing a push...

```
  properties([
  pipelineTriggers([
    [
      $class: 'BitBucketPPRTrigger',
      triggers : [
        [
          $class: 'BitBucketPPRPullRequestTriggerFilter',
          actionFilter: [
            $class: 'BitBucketPPRPullRequestMergedActionFilter',
          ]
        ],
        [
          $class: 'BitBucketPPRRepositoryTriggerFilter',
          actionFilter: [
            $class: 'BitBucketPPRRepositoryPushActionFilter',
            triggerAlsoIfNothingChanged: true,
            triggerAlsoIfTagPush: true,
            allowedBranches: "",
            isToApprove: false
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ])
])

pipeline {
  agent any

stages {
  stage('Build') {
      steps {
        echo 'Building...'

        echo 'Env vars for cloud pull request...'
        echo "BITBUCKET_SOURCE_BRANCH ${env.BITBUCKET_SOURCE_BRANCH}"
        echo "BITBUCKET_TARGET_BRANCH ${env.BITBUCKET_TARGET_BRANCH}"
        echo "BITBUCKET_PULL_REQUEST_LINK ${env.BITBUCKET_PULL_REQUEST_LINK}"
        echo "BITBUCKET_PULL_REQUEST_ID ${env.BITBUCKET_PULL_REQUEST_ID}"
        echo "BITBUCKET_PAYLOAD ${env.BITBUCKET_PAYLOAD}"

        echo "test deploy syntax cfg pipeline"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

when executing a git push on master branch I'm seeing this in jenkins system logs but the job in
not triggered within my multibranch pipeline...  any idea why?

```
Oct 21, 2020 2:16:30 PM INFO io.jenkins.plugins.bitbucketpushandpullrequest.BitBucketPPRHookReceiver doIndex
Received x-event-key repo:push from Bitbucket
Oct 21, 2020 2:16:30 PM INFO io.jenkins.plugins.bitbucketpushandpullrequest.processor.BitBucketPPRPayloadProcessorFactory createProcessor
Create BitBucketPPRRepositoryCloudPayloadProcessor
Oct 21, 2020 2:16:30 PM INFO io.jenkins.plugins.bitbucketpushandpullrequest.observer.BitBucketPPRObserverFactory createObservable
Add BitBucketPPRPushCloudObserver for BitBucketPPREvent [event=repo, action=push]
Oct 21, 2020 2:16:30 PM INFO io.jenkins.plugins.bitbucketpushandpullrequest.processor.BitBucketPPRRepositoryCloudPayloadProcessor buildActionForJobs
Instantiate BitBucketPPRRepositoryAction
Oct 21, 2020 2:16:30 PM INFO io.jenkins.plugins.bitbucketpushandpullrequest.action.BitBucketPPRRepositoryAction 
Received commit hook notification for branch: master
Oct 21, 2020 2:16:30 PM INFO io.jenkins.plugins.bitbucketpushandpullrequest.action.BitBucketPPRRepositoryAction 
Received commit hook type: branch
Oct 21, 2020 2:16:30 PM INFO io.jenkins.plugins.bitbucketpushandpullrequest.BitBucketPPRHookReceiver doIndex
Response sent.
```